# recursive function in class in python

Tags: python

I don't know, why isn't working that code in python. The problem is, that I can get numbers, but sometimes some numbers are uniform. And I want to do 5 different numbers between 1 and 90.

```
class lottery:
    def __init__(self):
        self.price = 50
    def list(self):
        numbers = []            
        for i in range(0,5):
            numbers.append(random.randint(0,90))
        for i in range(1,5):
            for j in range(0,i-1):
                if (numbers[i]==numbers[j]):
                    game.list()
        return numbers
game = lottery()
game.list()
```

Or is there any better way to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem? Do you get an error? It doesn't show any result?

Comment: No, I don't get an error message, but it doesn't work, becuase when I run a lot, there will be same numbers (e.g.:2,34,56,34,87)

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: create 5 different random numbers between 1 and 90

Comment: And you get the same numbers each time?

Comment: the do...while cycle should be better, but unluckily there isn't in python :/

Comment: No. Sometimes I get various numbers, but sometimes there are some similar :/

Comment: I believe that the OP takes issue with the repeated 34 in 2,34,56,34,87; they want 5 unique numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should import the `random` module:

```
import random
```

The problem is that you are *not returning* the result that you get from the recursive call, therefore you are still returning the `list` with repeated numbers. It should be:

```
def list(self):
    numbers = []
    for i in range(0, 5):
        numbers.append(random.randint(0, 90))
    for i in range(1, 5):
        for j in range(0, i - 1):
            if (numbers[i] == numbers[j]):
                return self.list()  # return
    return numbers
```

note that `self` is used to access to the instance of the class that calls the method. Also, don't forget to `print` the results:

```
game = lottery()
print game.list()
```

**Note:**

Don't use `list` as the name of a variable or method because it will hide the built-in definition of `list`.

Comment: None of these suggestions address the OP's actual problem; I suspect that the question merely omitted unnecessary elements like importing `random`.

Comment: @IstvanChung I just forgot to mention that the part `return self.list()` solved the issue. Edited.

Comment: While this "fixes" the question's code, it leaves the problems which were inherent in the original approach, which should be scrapped in favor of a real solution.

Comment: But this is still being a solution. I don't think this deserves a downvote.

Comment: Unfortunately, my vote is locked in, since I forgot to remove it after your edit to include `return self.list()`, and it's been too long since then :(. If it's edited again, I will be able to remove the downvote.

Comment: @IstvanChung done. And upvoted your answer since it's *a better way* to solve OP's problem (as he asked).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
def list(self):
    return random.sample(xrange(90), 5)
```

This is (especially for large values of 5) much more efficient than starting over every time your randomization creates a repeat, and also avoids the possibility of overflowing the stack.